# Java: Why do we us property change listeners instead of direct pointing to single value?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, listener

The idea of listener is, that of some field(or attribute) of an object changes, all "registered" listeners will be "notified" and copy the new value to their fields. 
However, is it not an **unnecessary complicated** and **redundant** design?
Here is a simple proposal to solve the problem with direct value pointing and in-boxing if need.
For example, in case of string field:

```
public class StringBox {

protected String value;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValueAtomic(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public StringBox(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public StringBox() {

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StringBox{" + "value=" + value + '}';
}

}
public class StringListenerReplacer {

    protected StringBox field;


public StringListenerReplacer(StringBox field) {
    this.field = field;
}

public void setField(String field){
    this.field.setValueAtomic(field);
}

public String getField(){
    return this.field.getValue();
}
}

public class DemoMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBox field = new StringBox("DemoMain");

    StringListenerReplacer s0 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);
    StringListenerReplacer s1 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);
    StringListenerReplacer s2 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);
    StringListenerReplacer s3 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);
    StringListenerReplacer s4 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);
    StringListenerReplacer s5 = new StringListenerReplacer(field);

    System.out.println("Now, it is quasi a listener set to the string field value, so if one object change it, it changes for all");

    System.out.println("s0.getField() = " + s0.getField());

    System.out.println("Now, for example s4 changes field");

    s4.setField("another value");

    System.out.println("s0.getField() = " + s0.getField());
    System.out.println("s1.getField() = " + s1.getField());
    System.out.println("s2.getField() = " + s2.getField());
    System.out.println("s3.getField() = " + s3.getField());
    System.out.println("s4.getField() = " + s4.getField());
    System.out.println("s5.getField() = " + s5.getField());

}

}
```

With listener design, not talking about it would look syntactically weird, 
 each of this object would have a reference to another one **(6*5 = 30 references)**, **6 copies** of the string field and with each change 
or the field, a firePropertyChange with **5 calls** in the loop over all listeners will be called.
Now i understand, why for example Eclipse or Netbeans IDE are extremely slow on weak laptops, working from the akku.
So the question is, why do people do use listeners **overall** in programming?

Answer (score 2):

> The idea of listener is, that of some field(or attribute) of an object changes, all "registered" listeners will be "notified" and copy the new value to their fields.

I think the premise of this is wrong. I'm a fan of using listeners, the observer pattern in general, but have never used them in that way.

You might want to execute an action when a button is clicked. For instance printing some text to the console. Rather than constantly polling the button for changes, with every listener, it's much more efficient if the button calls the listeners instead.

Even if you have a reference to the variable `isClicked` which is `true` during the frame the button was clicked, you would constantly have to check `if(isClicked) {...}`, with every listener.

Answer (score 0):

One big disadvantage I can see with your design is that it is necessary to have access to the `StringListenerReplacer` object in order to change a value and have it "listen" for the change.

What happens if I have dozens of different, barely-related classes or logical code blocks which may or may not affect the object in question? The listener pattern allows for a listener to be notified of a change no matter what state the program is in or what has access to it.

It's also much more useful for multithreading, wherein we might synchronize listeners across threads to wait for value changes or even remote calls. Those threads can be in completely different states or executing blocks of code and the listener will always be properly notified.

Answer (score 0):

The official name of the listener design is called observer.  You are correct that setting up listeners does add code and complexity.  As such you would not use listeners for simple POJO's.  You would use it mostly for events and queues.

A video game is a good example of where you would use the observable pattern, but there are countless.  I worked on a game where there were events all over the place.  One of the events was a pause event.  At first I would manually notify all the objects that needed to know about the pause events, every enemy and projectile and the music etc..  I kept doing this because of the costs and complexity of adding the observable pattern to this part of the game.  But after a while it became too difficult to notify all the objects manually as the list grew.  So I bit the bullet and implemented the observable pattern.  This had an overall affect of reducing complexity in my code.  With the observable pattern, any object that needed to be notified about the pause event would take it upon itself to register itself to be notified when that event occurred.

Events and queues might be a little obvious.  Let me give you a more mundane example, also involving the same video game.  The game was coded in JavaFX, which already has observable patterns built into their classes.  I registered listeners to be notified when objects on the screen changed.  For example I recall having an object X on the screen whose placement depended on the placement of another object Y.  So I setup a listener so that when the coordinates of object Y changed, I would rearrange object X on the screen.  This example shows how it could be useful even for properties of a class.